# SQL multiple where functions getting different result from single query

Tags: sql

Sorry for this seemingly easy question. I have a query that I can't seem to get to work. I want to pull the results for all of the where clauses as if they were a query in themselves. But instead of running this query 14 times and commenting out each where statement, I wanted to collate it so I get all the resultss. However I cannot seem to make it work with multiple and/or statements. What am I doing wrong?

````
where date >= '2022-01-22' and date <= '2022-02-19'
and

brand = 'company1' and marketplace = 'US' or
brand = 'company2' and marketplace = 'DE' or
brand = 'company3' and marketplace = 'US' or
brand = 'company4' and marketplace = 'UK' or
brand = 'company5' and marketplace = 'US' or
brand = 'company6' and marketplace = 'US' or
brand = 'company7' and marketplace = 'US' or
brand = 'company8' and marketplace = 'UK' or
brand = 'company9' and marketplace = 'UK' or
brand = 'company10' and marketplace = 'US' or
brand = 'company11' and marketplace = 'US' or
brand = 'company12' and marketplace = 'US' or
brand = 'company13' and marketplace = 'US' or
brand = 'company14' and marketplace = 'UK'

group by asin, brand, marketplace
order by ASP Asc; ```
````

Comment: Add parenthesis to enclose all `OR` predicates. That is: `where date >= '2022-01-22' and date <= '2022-02-19' and ( ... ) group by asin, brand, marketplace
order by ASP Ascp`.

Comment: You need parentheses. AND goes before OR...

Comment: However, hard-coded values like that often indicate something weird is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use or statement you need to group your cases
You can have OR and AND like this without defining your ( )

```
where date >= '2022-01-22' and date <= '2022-02-19'
and (
(brand = 'company1' and marketplace = 'US') or
(brand = 'company2' and marketplace = 'DE') or
(brand = 'company3' and marketplace = 'US') or
(brand = 'company4' and marketplace = 'UK') or
(brand = 'company5' and marketplace = 'US') or
(brand = 'company6' and marketplace = 'US') or
(brand = 'company7' and marketplace = 'US') or
(brand = 'company8' and marketplace = 'UK') or
(brand = 'company9' and marketplace = 'UK') or
(brand = 'company10' and marketplace = 'US') or
(brand = 'company11' and marketplace = 'US') or
(brand = 'company12' and marketplace = 'US') or
(brand = 'company13' and marketplace = 'US') or
(brand = 'company14' and marketplace = 'UK')
)
```